# I cannot find the element in html code below using Selenium Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Below is the HTML code for the toggle element. It is a side bar menu (nbn network rollout reports> that will display two links once clicked or expanded. I already tried "Click Element" keyword using "network rollout repots" but it didn't work.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#id24aff85" class="has-icon" aria-expanded="true">           

                    nbn™ network rollout reports


<small class="pull-right collapse-icon-chevron"></small>
</a>
```

Comment: what is the locator u tried?

Comment: I tried below keyword but didn't work:

Click Element    network rollout reports

I'm still a newbie in Robot Framework so I'm not really familiar with other techniques. Can someone suggest how to click the element "nbn network rollout reports" please? Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and what the exact error is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the element is visible, and indeed a hyperlink, the following should work:

```
Click Element     link=nbn™ network rollout reports
```

Otherwise an xpath approach for a more flexible search may be an alternative:

```
Click Element    xpath=//a[contains(text(),'network rollout reports')]
```